# How does UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionRefresh actually work?

Tags: ipados

I'm having a hard time understanding how [UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionRefresh](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/3197903-requestscenesessionrefresh?language=objc) actually works. According to Apple, this is used to update scenes that are in background. But does the API call something in your background scene to allow the UI to update or is it assumed that you've updated your background scene and this call will just capture your UI?